# Cognito token being used before issued at time

Tags: php, amazon-cognito

i'm using the Cognito authorization code to get my access tokens from AWS Cognito. So this is my current workflow:

1. No session data, forward user to hosted UI.
2. On login, return to PHP Application with the authorization code.
3. Use authorization code to get the tokens.
4. Validate the tokens using the `jwk` tokens.

So step 4 is where i'm stuck, as when validating the tokens, JWT is starting that i'm trying to decode the `access_token` before it is valid:

> Cannot handle token prior to 2022-05-26T13:45:17+0000

I have dumped out the code which displays this error to get the `iat` time and the time that it is being compared against:

```php
dd($payload->iat, ($timestamp + static::$leeway));
```

This outputs:

> 1653576011 1653576009

So there is a 0000000002 difference...

Now I can fix this by changing `leeway` to `10`, but this doesn't seem the correct thing to do... any ideas?

Below is the code:

```php
private function validateTokens($accessToken): bool
{
    $domain = implode('.', [ 'cognito-idp', $this->region, 'amazonaws.com' ]);
    $jwks = file_get_contents("https://$domain/{$this->pool_id}/.well-known/jwks.json");
    $jwks = collect(json_decode($jwks, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)['keys']);
    
    $jwks = $jwks->keyBy('kid')->map(static function ($current) {
        return (new JWKConverter())->toPEM($current);
    })->toArray();

    $jwt = new JWT();
    $jwt::$leeway = 10;
    
    $decoded = $jwt::decode($accessToken['access_token'], $jwks, ['RS256']);
    
    dd($decoded);
```